# UIButton remove style selected state

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I would like to remove the selected state effect from the UIButtons.

When pressed a blue capsule appears next to the UIButton.

[image: UIButton-selected-state]

**UPDATE with new problem**

UIButton with type:system selects the targeted button. After changing the UIButton type to custom. This effect was removed. Other buttons were pressed that are located in the same view.

This is part of the UIButton function, if pressed it should run the code in this IBAction. Two UIButtons are connected to this function. With type system it selected the right UIButton, with type custom it seems to select at random.

```
  - (IBAction) buttonAction:(id)sender
      {
         UIButton *btn = sender;

         btn.selected = !btn.selected; 

         if([sender tag] == 1){
            // run code UIButton 1
         }

         if([sender tag] == 2){

            // run code UIButton 2

         }
    }
```

I hope this is clear.

Comment: Thank you for entering the image

Comment: Change the button's type as custom

Comment: @RajeshKumarR How can I do that?

Comment: Have you created these buttons in storyboard?

Comment: No, a made a new xib file with a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the button from the xib file and change its type to custom in attributes inspector.

[image]

Comment: After changing the UIButton type to custom, this piece of code stopt working 
-- btn.selected = !btn.selected; -- I think the code doesn't select the UIButtons. Do you know how to get this piece of code working agian?

Comment: @MohamedElKawakibi Changing type to custom does nothing with selected property

Comment: Should I post about it with the code I'm using, to make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the second problem I described.

The UIButton type: custom doesn't have the selected trait as default.
The traits that were selected are: Button and User Interaction Enabled.
After selecting: selected it worked.

[traits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4H8m.png)